# How to use an ICollection navigation property with include()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get each user with its projects using entity framework core in a web api project in the controller with linq

I tried with this query but it gave me an empty object

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(x => x.userProjects.Select(up => up.UserId == x.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

I also tried this one and got the same result

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(x => x.userProjects.Where(up => up.UserId == x.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

This is the User class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public ICollection<UserProject> userProjects { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Project class

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the UserProject class

```
public class UserProject
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a json with each user and an array of its projects

Comment: Shouldn't that be just `_context.Users.Include(x => x.userProjects).ToListAsync()`? Or are you looking to get to the other side of the many-to-many?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i want something like [{user obj here, [{projects of the user}] }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple level of includes, you need `ThenInclude`.

```
var users = _context.Users
                    .Include(x => x.userProjects)
                        .ThenInclude(y => y.Project)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: i'm getting a non complete json! [{"id":1,"name":"Khaled","userProjects":[{"userId":1 ,,,, why does it stop?

Comment: @Khaled Not way I can tell with the information provided, but it's not related to EF core (unless there's an exception somewhere)

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer it was the right one. I don't know what was the problem but someone else had the same one and fixed it using this: services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        ); in the Configuration method in the startup class

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(u => u.userProjects)
                          .ThenInclude(up => up.Projects))
                          .Where(u => u.UserId == Id)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

What happens here:

You will retrieve all users which have `UserId = yourId` and also all the `UserProjects` and `Projects` of those users.

Example of code which shows you you can access all the projects of the first returned user:

```
var projectsForFirstUser = users.First().Select(x => x.UserProjects).Select(x => x.Project).ToList();
```

EDIT: Modified to `ThenInclude` because of EF Core.

Comment: The Where statement does not work, because im getting the properties of the user only

Comment: Can you give more details? It is normal that the returned variables to be of user type. If you want to access the projects, look at the second code snippet.

Comment: Im not getting the where statement, because the UserId property is in the userProject class and the Id property is in the user class and when i use the where statement i can only get the user properties